# Object detection app using Android studio and opencv

Tags: android-studio, opencv, machine-learning

I want to make an app which will detect the object, its name and distance from the user using opencv on Android studio. So i need to train the objects first. So is there any technique besides Tensorflow or Yolo with which i can train my model .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object detection requires classification and localization there are various Neural network architectures that can do it such as Faster RCNN, Yolo, SSD, etc. Tensorflow and darknet already have tools that make it easier to detect the objects. Other than darknet and TensorFlow, there is PyTorch but implementing it in the android app is a challenge. The best bet is to use Tensorflow as it gives you its lite version designed for mobile devices.